# Win OS Clipboard Targets vs. GtkClipboard Targets

Tags: winapi, gtk

We have a Gtk+ app running in Win.  It relies on the `GtkClipboard` and related machinery to perform Cut/Copy/Paste (CCP) via the Win OS clipboard.  All the CCP implemented thus far works correctly and we can CCP to/from our Gtk app with a variety of apps, for a number of Targets/formats.

However, there are strange differences between the Win OS clipboard "Targets" and the `GtkClipboard` "Targets", where "Targets" are the formats that the clipboard "owner" can convert into.

With the WinOS Clipboard Viewer (clpbrd.exe) running, and Copy'ing a selection from Excel, one can see the Targets that the clipboard owner (in this case Excel via OLE) can covert the currently copied selection.  The Excel specific Targets are "greyed out" in the sense that clpbrd.exe can't convert into those, but the recipient programs may have the machinery to make the conversion, as per the image below.  Presumably, this "greying" is due to Excel "attaching to the Win clipboard via the OleClipboard.

[image]

For example, we have code that can receive various Excel formats, such as SYLK, XML Spreadsheet etc.  For instance, if the Excel Copy'd selection is pasted with Gtk Target chosen to be XML Spreadsheet, then on the Gtk-side, we receive an XML "text" stream that can be parsed with our XML parser etc.  This is all as it should be.

However, if on the Gtk-side, one performs a `gtk_clipboard_request_targets()` to obtain the, presumed to be, same list of Targets (formats) that the clipboard owner (Excel) can convert into.  However, we print out the Targets Gtk finds, it is a list as per this image:

[image]

Although there are a great number of similarities, the two lists are different.  For example, the original (clibrd.exe) list had SYLK as one of the Targets/formats that the owner (Excel) was prepared to convert to.  Yet, the list produced by Gtk does not include SYLK.

This discrepancy occurs for a variety of Win/Excel version combinations/permutations (XP, Win7, 32/64, Excel XP, Excel 10 etc).

... what gives?  Clearly, in the OS clipboard, Excel claims to be able to convert to SYLK, so why does the Gtk query not see that?  The Gtk query certainly sees Excel specific formats (e.g. any of the BIFF's etc), so why the odd discrepancy?

Comment: GTK+ is probably not using `OleGetClipboard()`. What formats can you get out of that?

Comment: Note that `OleGetClipboard()` is just a convenience function that does the work of dealing with OLE objects; if you don't use it you'd have to deal with them manually. I wouldn't know how; in fact, I'm not fully sure what `OleGetClipboard()` can do that `GetClipboardData()` can't, or vice versa.

Comment: My question is much simpler.  I don't use any of the functions to which you refer in my question.  I use only two things:  One is the standard Win clipboard viewer (clpbrd.exe), which generates the first image/list above.  The other is the standard `GtkClipboard` (Targets) request, which produces the second list above.  Clearly, the list produced by Win is very similar to that produced by Gtk.  The question is, why are there "odd differences", such as Win's list SYLK, but Gkt's does not.   As far as OLE is concerned, I am not doing anything with it, I simply stated that Office attaches OLE.